# How to find intersect rows when condition depend on some columns in one table

Tags: php, mysql

Table **subscribe**

```
subscriber | subscribeto (columns)
1          | 5
1          | 6
1          | 7
1          | 8
1          | 9
1          | 10
2          | 5
2          | 6
2          | 7
```

There are two users that have id 1 and 2. They subscribe to various user and I inserted these data to table **subscribe**. Column **subscriber** indicates who is subscriber and column **subscribeto** indicates who they've subscribe to. From the above table can conclude that;
 user id=1 subscribed to 6 users
user id=2 subscribed to 3 users

I want to find mutual of subscription (like Facebook is mutual friends)
user 1 subscribe to user 5,6,7,8,9,10
user 2 subscribe to user 5,6,7
So, mutual subscription of user 1 and 2 are: 5,6,7

And I'm trying to create SQL statement..
I give you **user** table for my SQL statement and I think we can use only **subscribe** table but I can't figure out.

Table **user**

```
userid  (columns)
1
2
3
...
...
```

**SQL**

```
"select * from user where (select count( 1 ) from subscribe where subscriber = '1' and subscribeto = user.userid) and (select count( 1 ) from subscribe where subscriber = '2' and subscribeto = user.userid);"
```

This SQL can work correctly, but it very slow for thousands of columns. Please provide better SQL for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(subscriber INT NOT NULL
,subscribeto INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(subscriber,subscribeto)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,5),
(1,6),
(1,7),
(1,8),
(1,9),
(1,10),
(2,5),
(2,6),
(2,7);

SELECT x.subscribeto mutual_friends 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.subscribeto = x.subscribeto 
 WHERE x.subscriber = 1 
   AND y.subscriber = 2;
+----------------+
| mutual_friends |
+----------------+
|              5 |
|              6 |
|              7 |
+----------------+
```